# How to capture Facebook notifications?

Tags: javascript, facebook, notifications

How could you capture the "Notifications" (events) from a Facebook profile, preferably using Javascript (but open to others if that's infeasible)?

Answer (score 0):

Request the "manage_notifications" Extended Permission when users approve access for your app. They may deny you this ability (as it is ["Extended"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)), so ensure that your app is capable of working without this information